# What code does Facebook, Skype, etc. look for to make their thumbnails?

Tags: html, facebook, thumbnails, preview, skype

When I post a link in Facebook or Skype, they display some of the content as a thumbnail, but it's not the whole page, usually it's the most representative image. I would like my own pages to have nice thumbnails in Facebook, Skype, etc. too. What code do they look for to do this?

Comment: your logic about your project depend of your problem to resolve friend

Comment: Use the `<meta>` tags from [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Xufox mentioned, the 

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://your.site.com/image.jpg">`
 meta tag from [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) is used for that.
Scroll down a little to the full image sample under `Structured Properties` and you'll see some additional parameters.